# binary formatter deserialize from memory stream freezing

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I am trying to do a client-server application that communicate through sockets and their messages are serialez and deserialised using BinaryFormatter. My code is freezing and does absolutely nothing when reaching deserialize, and I don't understand why since I have no exception. I also can not step into with debugger, everything is freezing. This is my code:

```
 public class Serializer
    {
        public static MemoryStream ToStream(object obj)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
            return stream;
        }

        public static object FromStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting from stream");
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            object rez = formatter.Deserialize(stream); //NEVER GOES OVER THIS
            Console.WriteLine("Starting deserialization" + rez);
            return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
```

```
public class Connection
    {
        private Socket socket;
        public Connection(Socket socket)
        {
            this.socket = socket;
            Console.WriteLine($"Connected to client: {socket.RemoteEndPoint}");
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Execute(socket));
        }

        private void Execute(Socket socket)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var buffer = new byte[2048];
                var bytesCount = socket.Receive(buffer);
                if(bytesCount != 0)
                {
                    var msgReceived = (Message)Serializer.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received msg: {msgReceived.Content}");
                }
               /* var msg = new Message { Content = "Hello World2!" };
                Console.WriteLine($"Sending msg with content: {msg.Content}");
                MemoryStream stream = Serializer.ToStream(msg);
                var bytesSent = socket.Send(stream.GetBuffer());*/

                Console.WriteLine("Trying again");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
```

client code:

```
  var host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            var ipAddress = host.AddressList.First();
            var serverEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 9000);

            Socket serverSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Connect(serverEndpoint);

            Console.WriteLine($"Successfully connected to server on: {serverSocket.RemoteEndPoint}");

            while (true)
            {
                var msg = new Message { Content = "Hello World!" };
                Console.WriteLine($"Sending msg with content: {msg.Content}");
                MemoryStream stream = Serializer.ToStream(msg);
                var bytesSent = serverSocket.Send(stream.GetBuffer());
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting to receive");

                var buffer = new byte[2048];
                int bytesReceived = serverSocket.Receive(buffer);
                if (bytesReceived != 0)
                {
                    var receivedMessage = (Message)Serializer.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer));
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {receivedMessage.Content}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Received done");

            }
```

server code :

```
var host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            var ipAddress = host.AddressList.First();
            var localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 9000);
            var serverSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
            serverSocket.Listen(1);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client");
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
                var connection = new Connection(clientSocket);
            }
```

I also checked the byteCount and they are arriving to the server, also the buffer is not empty, I don't understand why deserialize does nothing..

Comment: Is it possible that it's getting hung on your second call (`return formatter.Deserialize`)? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654299/binaryformatter-deserialize-hangs-the-whole-thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call Deserialize twice, I think problem here:

```
object rez = formatter.Deserialize(stream); //NEVER GOES OVER THIS
Console.WriteLine("Starting deserialization" + rez);
return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

I think you can use methods like that:

```
    private byte[] SerializeMessage(Message msg)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        byte[] buf;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, msg);
            buf = new byte[stream.Length];
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

     private Message DeserializeMessage(byte[] buff)
     {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            ConnectingMessage msg;
            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buff))
            {
                msg = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as Message;
            }

            return msg;           
     }
```

Also methods Send/Receive are synchronous, they block thread execution.

The description of the asynchronous option is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-an-asynchronous-client-socket

Comment: I called it twice because I was trying to get the debugger into deserialize method, it is the same result if I call it once..

Comment: I ran your code and it worked ok until the place where we are trying to read from the stream a second time, an exception is thrown there.
Try replace `return formatter.Deserialize(stream);` with `return rez;`

Answer (score 0):

Only one piece of code can run at the same time. While that infinute loop `while (true)` runs, no other code will ever be able to run.

You will need to add some Multitasking to this project. The minimum amount, that is required for every word processor. However you also seem to be programming in console. And from my experience, console and Multitasking do not mix that well. You need to keep the programm alive, without blocking input.

My advice for learning Multitasking, is a BackgroundWorker in Windows Forms. The BGW is dated, usese Threads wich would be unessary here and should not be used in productive code. But it is perhaps the best "Training Wheels" for multitasking and -threading I know off.